# How to Update &Delete PostgreSQL Entity framework6 on C#

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have Postgresql entity framework6 work on C#. I can do Database populate and insert as code.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Populate
        ProjectContext context = new ProjectContext();
        context.TbUser.ToList()
            .ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} 
       {1}",p.name,p.surname)));
    }
```

Insert

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Insert
        ProjectContext context = new ProjectContext();
        context.TbUser.Add(new TbUser {name= "aa", surname = "bb" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I search around but not found solution for UPDATE and DELETE. Appreciated with thanks for all answer.

Comment: Hello, take a look at [this site](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/crud-operation-in-connected-scenario-entity-framework.aspx) and give a try.

Comment: Hi Vagner Lucas, How to update student, let's say id=2(not first record)?. From example code ->var std = context.Students.First<Student>();<- . Does it mean update student on first record?

Comment: You should try learning Linq. Actually, there are lots of examples if you google it. Take a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to make more issue. Just want to know how to query update and delete with Entity.

Comment: The exactly LinQ is here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx.